# Best way to map a string to an array depending on other array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array:

```
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve',
  col1 : 1,
  col2 : 0,
  col3 : 1
}, {
  name: 'john',
    col1 : 1,
  col2 : 1,
  col3 : 0
}, {
  name: 'jane',
  col1 : 0,
  col2 : 1,
  col3 : 1
}];
```

I need a field inside the array that has a string of the names of columns col1, col2, col3 if they are 1. Sample outcome is:

```
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve',
  col1 : 1,
  col2 : 0,
  col3 : 1,
  account : "col1,col3"
} //etc
}]
```

I can currently achieve this with

```
var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
  o.account = ""
  if (o.col1 > 0) {o.account  = o.account + "col1,"} ;
  if (o.col2 > 0) {o.account= o.account + "col2,"} ;
  if (o.col3 > 0) {o.account= o.account + "col3,"} ;
  o.account = o.account.slice(0, -1);
  return o;
})

console.log(result)
```

but as a novice to JS this feels inefficient. My actual array has a dozen such columns being evaluated.

Edit: finished product with assistance from the accepted answer:

```
var bool_cols = ["col1","col2","col3"]

data.forEach(x => {
        x.services = Object.keys(x).filter (y => bool_cols.includes(x) && x[y] == 1).join (',');
    })
```

I like how I can expand the filter criteria indefinitely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
arrOfObj.forEach ( (x) => {
    x.account = Object.keys(x).filter (y => x[y] == 1).join (',');
})
```

Comment: Could I do that on only certain parts of the array? Col1, 2, and 3 but not Name?

Comment: @DCUFan7 you can add more conditions inside the filter function like ```filter (y => x[y] == 1 && y.contains("col") )```

Comment: I love this for making use of filter and join. Looking like includes works for me as well on the second filter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would loop over the keys of the object. And check if key starts with `'col'`

```js
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve',
  col1 : 1,
  col2 : 0,
  col3 : 1
}, {
  name: 'john',
    col1 : 1,
  col2 : 1,
  col3 : 0
}, {
  name: 'jane',
  col1 : 0,
  col2 : 1,
  col3 : 1
}];

const res = arrOfObj.map(x => {
  let acc = [];
  Object.keys(x).forEach(k => {
    if(k.startsWith('col') && x[k] === 1){
      acc.push(k)
    }
  })
  return {...x, account: acc.join(',')}
});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `var Object.keys(object);` to get the keynames of the object and then check the values.

```
var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
  var keys = Object.keys(o);
  var keyArray = [];
  keys.forEach((key) => {
      if (o[key] > 0) { 
        // Declare the account property, only
        // when it's needed. Otherwise, get it out of the foreach
        keyArray.push(key);
      }
  });
  o['account'] = keyArray.join(',');
});
```

Comment: Updated with the comma.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras that pattern is just bad code, just push into an array and then join by comma at the end ...

Comment: Why bother setting the account to an empty string before appending the key. Just set it to the key. Also, working the comma separator into the appended string value just causes confusion and makes it more difficult to manage later when inputs change. Using a join instead, solves all that.

Comment: Because += resulted in `undefinedcol1`.